# Pandas dataframe plot regressions curves for each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that look like this picture below. I want to plot a graph of the numbers vs the Date for each of the columns (Android, angularjs, etc). I tried using `series.unstack().plot`, but it gives me a line plot that looks like figure 2. Instead of a line plot I'm looking to just plot the best fit curve for each of these columns as I am just looking to compare growths (on the same graph).  [image: DataFrame][image: Lineplot]

Comment: Hey that graph looks like it does a reasonable job of comparing the series to one another. Are you looking to smooth out the noise? How about a rolling average?

Comment: Can you post this data frame as text? Orr post `df.head(10).to_dict()` ?

Comment: @smj Yes, I'm looking to smooth out the curve so as to not show those jagged lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide an answer using rolling averages, which may be useful to see changes in trend (of which it looks like there are some in your original data), which are obscured by fitting a line. This example provides a 120 observation rolling window, which does a nice job of smoothing the data while retaining local trend changes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'val_1': pd.Series((np.random.randn(1000) * (1 - np.random.rand(1000)))).cumsum(),
        'val_2': pd.Series((np.random.randn(1000) * (1 - np.random.rand(1000)))).cumsum()
    }
)

window = 120

rolling = data.rolling(window).mean()

rolling.columns = [i + '_rolling_' + str(window) for i in data.columns]

ax = data.plot(alpha = .5)

rolling.plot(ax = ax)
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want, but I'll give it a shot.

Since you didn't provide the data, let's create four random walks with different drifts:

```
s1 = pd.Series(0.3  + np.random.normal(size=[100])).cumsum()
s2 = pd.Series(-0.3 + np.random.normal(size=[100])).cumsum()
s3 = pd.Series(0.1  + np.random.normal(size=[100])).cumsum()
s4 = pd.Series(0.1  + np.random.normal(size=[100])).cumsum()
```

And the `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s1':s1,
                   's2':s2,
                   's3':s3,
                   's4':s4})
```

Such that the plot is

[image]

Now, to fit the best line, you can use [`numpy.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) specifying degree to be 1

```
b1, a1 = np.polyfit(range(100), s1, 1)
b2, a2 = np.polyfit(range(100), s2, 1)
b3, a3 = np.polyfit(range(100), s3, 1)
b4, a4 = np.polyfit(range(100), s4, 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.plot(np.arange(100), a1 + b1*np.arange(100), color='red')
ax.plot(np.arange(100), a2 + b2*np.arange(100), color='blue')
ax.plot(np.arange(100), a3 + b3*np.arange(100), color='green')
ax.plot(np.arange(100), a4 + b4*np.arange(100), color='black')
```

Such that you get

[image]

To compare the best-fitting line with the actual initial graph, set up the same colors when plotting:

```
ax.plot(np.arange(100), a1 + b1*np.arange(100), color='red')
ax.plot(np.arange(100), a2 + b2*np.arange(100), color='blue')
ax.plot(np.arange(100), a3 + b3*np.arange(100), color='green')
ax.plot(np.arange(100), a4 + b4*np.arange(100), color='black')

ax.plot(df.s1, color='red')
ax.plot(df.s2, color='blue')
ax.plot(df.s3, color='green')
ax.plot(df.s4, color='black')
```

[image]